# qt installer framework, environment variables

Tags: qt, frameworks, environment-variables, installation

This should be really simple with an installer framework.  I'm trying to append a folder to the users PATH environment variable in Windows 10.
In my packages installscript.qs I have tried:

```
component.addOperation("EnvironmentVariable", "APP_DIR", "@TargetDir@", true);
```

which creates and sets a new variable.  But how do I append to an existing variable?  I've tried:

```
installer.executeDetached("set", "PATH=%PATH%;@TargetDir@");
```

which doesn't seem to do anything, and:

```
var args = "PATH=%PATH%;@TargetDir@"
installer.executeDetached("set", args);
```

which also doesn't appear to do anything.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your installscript.qs try something like this

```
Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    // call default implementation
    component.createOperations();
    // ... add custom operations
    var winpath = installer.environmentVariable("PATH") + ";" + installer.value("TargetDir");
    component.addElevatedOperation("EnvironmentVariable","PATH",winpath,true);
}
```

Comment: Operation installer.environmentVariable("PATH") returns whole path variable (both system and user part, while addElevatedOperation writes to  either user or system. In result user path will have system path values as well, which is not good

Answer (score 2):

You can use powershell in your packages installscript.qs:

```
Component.prototype.createOperations = function()
{
    // call default implementation
    component.createOperations();

    var target_dir = installer.value("TargetDir").split("/").join("\\");

    // Add to the path
    component.addOperation("Execute", "powershell", "[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(\"Path\", [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable(\"Path\",\"User\") + \";" + target_dir + "\", \"User\")");
}
```